# URISyntaxException: Expected scheme name at index 0 in VCard android

Tags: android, android-contacts, vcf-vcard

I am exporting contacts from device using below dependency:

```
implementation 'com.googlecode.ez-vcard:ez-vcard:0.11.3'
```

While exporting, some times, Users facing issue in live application on play store. Below is the code for add impp object in vcard:

```
contact.IMs.forEach {mIM->
                    try {
                        val mLabel = if(mIM.label.isNullOrEmpty()) mIM.value else mIM.label
                        val impp = when (mIM.type) {
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.PROTOCOL_AIM -> Impp.aim(mIM.value)
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.PROTOCOL_YAHOO -> Impp.yahoo(mIM.value)
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.PROTOCOL_MSN -> Impp.msn(mIM.value)
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.PROTOCOL_ICQ -> Impp.icq(mIM.value)
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.PROTOCOL_SKYPE -> Impp.skype(mIM.value)
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.PROTOCOL_GOOGLE_TALK -> Impp(HANGOUTS, mIM.value)
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.PROTOCOL_QQ -> Impp(QQ, mIM.value)
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Im.PROTOCOL_JABBER -> Impp(JABBER, mIM.value)
                            else -> Impp(mLabel, mIM.value)
                        }
                        card.addImpp(impp)
                    }catch (e: Exception){
                        crashlytics.setCustomKey("Contact IMs", "Label: "+mIM.label+" Value: "+mIM.value+" Type: "+mIM.type)
                        Applog.e(TAG, e)
                    }
                }
```

On line `card.addImpp(impp)`, I am getting the below error:

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme name at index 0: :
   at com.allbackup.helpers.Applog.e(Applog.java:20)
   at com.allbackup.helpers.VcfExporter.exportContacts(VcfExporter.java:133)
   at com.allbackup.workers.WorkerViewModel$backupContactData$2.invokeSuspend(WorkerViewModel.java:151)
   at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(BaseContinuationImpl.java:33)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.java:106)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.java:571)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.java:750)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.java:678)
   at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.java:665)
```

As I found the reason for that. It's happening mostly because the label and value are empty.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply skip IMs that have no value:

```
contact.IMs.forEach { mIM ->
    
    // skip illegal IMs
    if (mIM.value.isNullOrEmpty()) return@forEach

    try {
        ...
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I am also getting errors while the value is there. which is not matching in any if condition.

Comment: then you need to verify the URI in `mIM.value` is a valid URI, the exception says it is expecting a scheme (e.g. http / https / ftp) but is getting something illegal instead.

Comment: No, It shouldn't be any URL. it should be a contact account path where it stores like google talk, yahoo, skype, etc.

Comment: not a URL but a URI, and URI always contains a scheme part which is the word that comes before the "//" part. that is missing from that IM value, the value should be able to be parsed by https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri - see also the part about the scheme there